# Why is this code able to access a null pointer without causing a crash?

Tags: c, pointers, crash, null-pointer

I have come across the following piece of code, which finds the offset of a member within a structure. However I am not able to make out why it does not crash, even though it tries to derefer a NULL pointer

```
struct a_
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    int offset = &(((struct a_ *) 0x0)->b);
    printf ("offset of b = %x\n", offset);
} 

Output = 4
```

Comment: Technically it's undefined behavior, however any decent compiler will be able to resolve the expression during compilation so no null-pointer access happens.

Comment: Actually it is not de referencing the pointer NULL aka 0. It gets the address of the field `b` within a variable of type `struct a_` placed on the address 0. Hence it gets the offset of `b` in `struct a_`

Comment: It happens to match the form of `offsetof` (at least some implementations), but purists will argue that it cannot be computed (been there, been attacked).

Comment: @ThomasDickey, Yes this is an offsetof implementation. I have seen this on many platforms and this works fine. I am not able to understand then why it is said to be unexpected behavior.

Comment: "unexpected" and "undefined" are different.  Back to the question: none of the people in prior discussion was able to provide useful information.

Answer (score 4):

> However I am not able to make out why it does not crash, even though it tries to derefer a NULL pointer.

You are forming an invalid address which is undefined behavior but there is no dereference of NULL pointer because of the `&` operator that cancels the dereference.

Comment: Unable to comprehend what the standard states. Can you please elaborate more

Comment: The quote from the standard appears to be unrelated to the comment about the standard as well as unrelated to the actual question.

Comment: @ThomasDickey agree, I cannot find the exact quote, I remove it for now